# how to log tracebacks from uncaught crashes?

Tags: python, logging, traceback

I run a headless and unmanned server which logs everything to a remote server. The application I run there also does this via a `SysLogHandler`. It works fine.

I have cases where the program crashes (in places not handled by a `try: except:`) and I would like to log that way the traceback as well. Is this at all possible?

I am specifically talking about unexpected tracebacks , I know that I can [log exceptions in an `except:` clause](http://www.alexconrad.org/2013/02/loggingexception.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a custom [`excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).

> When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls sys.excepthook
>     with three arguments, the exception class, exception instance, and a traceback
>     object

---

```
import sys
import logging
logger = ...

def excepthook(type_, value, traceback):
    logger.exception(value)
    # call the default excepthook
    sys.__excepthook__(type_, value, traceback)

sys.excepthook = excepthook
```